# Return file info - Node.js file upload API

Tags: node.js, azure, api, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to Node and am trying to create a file upload API endpoint. I have the following code...

```
const azureStorageConfig = {
    accountName: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    accountKey: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY,
    blobURL: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BLOB_URL,
    containerName: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME
};

uploadFileToBlob = async (file, defectId, type) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var blobName;
        if (type == "initPestControlReport") {
            var blobName = defectId + '/Initial Visit/' + defectId + '_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '-001' + '_' + file.originalname.replace(/\s/g, '');

            const stream = getStream(file.buffer);
            const streamLength = file.buffer.length;

            const blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService(azureStorageConfig.accountName, azureStorageConfig.accountKey); 
            blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(azureStorageConfig.containerName, `${blobName}`, stream, streamLength, err => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {

                }
            });
        }
    });
};

const imageUpload = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const image = await uploadFileToBlob(req.file, req.body.defectId, req.body.type);
        return res.json(image);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};

// Upload initial visit report files
app.post('/v1/initrepfileupload', singleFileUpload.single('initRepImg'), imageUpload)
```

Files are uploaded to Azure BLOB storage but nothing is returned to the browser.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you want to return to the browser?

Comment: Anything that tells the browser issuing the ajax request that the request is complete. Status 200 would be fine. I tried return res.status(200).send() but doesn't seem to work.